# How to create an entry in google cloud firestore in python for a timestamp

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a python 3.7 based cloud function.  I have a value for seconds since epoch.  I can add a series of entries for a document as string, integer etc.  I can not add a timestamp though.

Here is a simple code snippet.

```
db = firestore.Client(project=project_id)

# the event dictionary already has some values in it.  Add a timestamp.
#

# This is a reference to javascript api.  Oddly enough this page does not have
# python listed.
# https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp
#
# This will add a timestamp as a string value.
event['mqtt_timestamp_rfc3339'] = mqtt_timestamp_rfc3339 # add the timestamp as a string

# this adds a the value as a number of seconds since epoch
event['timestamp_secs'] = mqtt_timestamp  # add the timestamp as timestamp class

# This fails.
# firestore.types.Value.timestamp_value(seconds=mqtt_timestamp.timestamp())  

# This actually updates the collection
doc_ref = db.collection(u'sensor-data').add(event)
```

The only thing I have seen so far from the example code is adding a timestamp which appears to be server time. In this case, I have a device which relays its info to a second device which in turn updates to pub/sub.  I don't really care about when the cloud function is called.  I want to know when the first device generated the event which could be considerable minutes before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method works for a cloud function using python 3.7.

```
doit():

    # stuff snipped for brevity

    # unpack timestamp as string from buffer
    mqtt_timestamp_str = mqtt_timestamp_bytes.decode("utf-8")
    # generate timestamp from string
    mqtt_timestamp = datetime.fromisoformat(mqtt_timestamp_str)
    # create as RFC339 string
    mqtt_timestamp_rfc3339 = rfc3339(mqtt_timestamp, utc=True, use_system_timezone=False)

    # stuff snipped. event is a dictionary with stuff to put in firebase

    # add the timestamp as RFC339 String
    event['mqtt_timestamp_rfc3339'] = mqtt_timestamp_rfc3339 
    event['timestamp'] = mqtt_timestamp  

    # update firebase
    doc_ref = db.collection(u'sensor-data').add(event)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using firebase timestamp function but it will save the server time regionwise..

```
client.collection('sensor-data').document('mydoc').set({
    'mytime':firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP
})
```

Comment: Yes I saw that.  I’m looking to specify the time in python as can be done in the JavaScript api docs.

Comment: This solves my problem. In my test `datetime.now()` sends local time but Firestore thinks it's UTC time, while `firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP` sets the correct timestamp that also gets correctly converted/displayed in Firestore console. Thanks!

Comment: this is the correct answer and the easy way to set the timestamp, use `firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP` to save your life.

Answer (score 3):

Firestore stores timestamps in a typed manner and it's not an integer like JavaScript's millisecond or a UNIX epoch. Like so:
[image]

This means that whichever language's package you use should take care of this (meaning it supply the expected date/time data to/from Firebase). For example in case of a Kotlin Android application my [RemoteAssetMapper.kt](https://github.com/DIYGPSTracker/DIYGPSTracker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/dev/csaba/diygpstracker/data/remote/RemoteAssetMapper.kt) has a `fun mapDateToTimestamp(date: Date): Timestamp` function which converts `java.util.Date` to `com.google.firebase.Timestamp`.

In your case Python has a package `google-cloud-firestore` I assume you are using in your cloud function. I haven't used Firestore with Python yet, but from the [example codes](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#python_1) it looks like that this Python package should be able to take regular Python `datetime` object and convert that and supply the required data to Firestore:

```
data = {
    u'stringExample': u'Hello, World!',
    u'booleanExample': True,
    u'numberExample': 3.14159265,
    u'dateExample': datetime.datetime.now(),
    u'arrayExample': [5, True, u'hello'],
    u'nullExample': None,
    u'objectExample': {
        u'a': 5,
        u'b': True
    }
}

db.collection(u'data').document(u'one').set(data)
```

Now in your case you may receive timestamps from IoT edge devices through MQTT protocol which sounds like to be possibly a UNIX epoch time. I'd start to look at `datetime.fromtimestamp` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) or `datetime.utcfromtimestamp`. You need to deal with time zones! Then once you have the Python datetime, theoretically - by the documentation - you can supply that as the Firestore timestamp, the pip package will take care of the rest of the conversion.

Comment: the datetime.now() is the current time upon executing the code.  I answered the question yesterday as shown below.  You can see that I am using datetime.fromisoformat() to get a datetime object from the timestamp string sent by the edge device.  Thanks for helping though.

Comment: OK, I didn't see your answer. Basically you kinda figured out what I explained: you just supply the Python native `datetime` object and the rest is handled by the `google-cloud-firestore` package internally. By the question it sounded like you receive the date in UNIX epoch tick.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  No worries.  Originally I thought you had to supply a seconds  since epoch.  In my original questions, I had this link in the comments: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp  It has a constructor which takes seconds since epoch as the constructor parameter.  I appreciate your assistance.  I'm new to firebase so it was confusing.  Also if you notice that webpage has all language references except for python.  Why is that?